# In any sort of Mobile/Web combo application, how would they synchronize the data between the 2 databases?

Tags: android, mongodb, sqlite, mobile, data-synchronization

All:

We have a software application with

1) Web-based component
2) Mobile-based component

Our 1) Web-based component  uses

a) MongoDB as the Database

b) ASP.NET C#

Our 2) Mobile-based component uses

a) Java

b) SQL Lite

However, both the databases have the same tables, but we have Not created any sort of bridge table between the collections in  MongoDB and the tables in the SQL Lite.

In any sort of Mobile/Web combo application, how would they synchronize the data between the 2 databases?  I'm looking for typical solutions that the software industry uses.

*******Updated Questions************************

Some C# programmers on Stackoverflow[dot]com mentioned that it might be good idea to specify the ObjectId as a String.

It just gave me an thought, would it be a a good idea  Mobile-based component which uses SQL Lite to have some bridge table that contains an ObjectId as String so that they can synchronize the data between the Mobile-based SQL Lite database, and the Web-based MongoDB Database?

Would the aforementioned approach have any disadvantages? If yes, please tell me the disadvantages.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve synchronization between mobile and web databases. For example you could make a separate table for different data-types versions on both mobile and web.. and each time the mobile app is opened it should fetch the web's "versions" and compare it with the local mobile versions.. Hope you're getting me here

Comment: When you say separate table for different data-types versions, do you mean a bridge
tables on the mobileside and bridge tables on the webside?  Each bridge table would
have rows with mobilesideId and a websideId.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: @sharp-edge Sorry about disturbing, however, could you please take a look at my updated question?  Sorry for any trouble.